# Как правильно прописать пути в PATH для python2.6?

Tags: python, python-2.x

У меня есть стенд и на нём стоит дистрибутив Linux Mandriva 2005. Именно его и нужно использовать. Там по умолчанию стоит python версии 2.4. Я скачал, сконфиругировал, собрать и установил в папку /home/lib/python2.6  python версии 2.6 пробовал добавлять путь к нему в PATH, но всё безрезультатно. При кажой перезагрузке python2.6 не работает, только если зайти в папку /home/lib/python2.6/bin и запустить `./python2.6` и то он запустится с ошибкой readline() но работать будет. Как мне правильно прописать пути к нему? Куда добавить? Чтобы нормально работал и чтобы я мог спокойно в командной строке писать `python2.6`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PATH не помогает потому, что bash смотрит в нём по порядку. В по порядку это /bin, /usr/bin и т.п. Вам надо просто добавить новый питон в другом порядке:

```
export PATH=/usr/lib/python2.6/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: у меня в /usr/lib/ нет python2.6 есть только python2.4 который видимо по умолчанию был там установлен в системе. Наверное мне нужно написать export PATH= /home/lib/python2.6/bin:$PATH  или нет?